# Restful WS using spring to return Excel file in xml response

Tags: web-services, rest, spring-mvc

I have a requirement to make a Restful WebService End point which will return the generated excel file in xml response.

Basically generation of Excel is conditional, There can be some cases when the end point will not be able to generate the excel based on my logic, Hence I want to add a response header parameter which will first tell the RestClint whether the response has any excel or not. if present, then only the RestClient will further process the xml response and receive the Excel binary. If not, the RestClient will not process further.

But I am totally new to Restful WS and not sure if these requirement can be achieved. Hence need a pointer or reference.

Thanks.

Comment: Just make xml with some falg with Excel is available or not , then check based on that.like <root><response>xlsok</response> remaining tags go here ..</root>.

Comment: Hello Sunleo, Can you please give some reference for your comments.